# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING

Tags: php, api

I keep getting this T_STRING Parse error im not sure what it is but its on line 34 towards the bottom, any help is appreciated.

```
<form action="product_search">
<input type="text" name="search" value="<? echo htmlentities($_GET['search']); ?>"/>
<input type="submit" value="Search"/>
</form>
<?
$search_items = urlencode($_GET['search']);
// $search_items = 'eee';
$items = simplexml_load_file('http://api.shopping.com/dsp/linkin_id-8005272/keyword-'.$search_items);

if (($items) && (strlen($search_items) > 1)) {
print "<pre>\n";
foreach ($items->result->domain->{domain-listing} as $item) {
print l($item->title, $item->url)."<br/>";
}
print '</pre>';
}
else {
?>
Search for products-- computers, eee pcs, sub-notebooks, and all that great stuff!
<?
}
?>

<?
$tids = explode(',',arg(2));
foreach ($tids as $tid) {
$term_info = taxonomy_get_term($tid);
$search_items = urlencode($term_info->name);
$items = simplexml_load_file('http://publisher.api.shopping.com/publisher/3.0/rest/GeneralSearch?identity.apiKey=[API KEY]&tr.trackingId=[LINKIN ID]&nf.keyword='.$search_items);

if (($items) && (strlen($search_items) > 1)) {
foreach ($items->categories->category->items->offer as $item) {
print '<div style="float: left; width: 120px; padding: 10px; overflow: auto; display: block;">';
//right here is the error
print '<a rel="nofollow" onclick="javascript:_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/outgoing/article_exit_link/789591']);" href="'.$item->offerURL.'"><img src="'.$item->imageList->image[0]->sourceURL.'" width="100"></a>';
print "<br/>".l($item->name, $item->offerURL, array(), NULL, NULL, TRUE);
print '</div>';
}
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be careful with your single and double quotes. On that line, you have

```
'<a rel="nofollow" onclick="javascript:_gaq.push(['
```

That opens and closes your string. the _trackPageview then causes the error, as it is not part of the string.

You can try something like (untested) below:

```
print '<a rel="nofollow" onclick="javascript:_gaq.push([\'_trackPageview\', \'/outgoing/article_exit_link/789591\']);" href="\'.$item->offerURL.\'"><img src="\'.$item->imageList->image[0]->sourceURL.\'" width="100"></a>';
```

By adding a \ before each ', you escape it so that it is considered part of your string.

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the single quotes in the onclick-code:

```
print '<a rel="nofollow" onclick="javascript:_gaq.push([\'_trackPageview\', \'/outgoing/article_exit_link/789591\']);" href="'.$item->offerURL.'"><img src="'.$item->imageList->image[0]->sourceURL.'" width="100"></a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape quotes:

```
print '<a rel="nofollow" onclick="javascript:_gaq.push([\'_trackPageview\', \'/outgoing/article_exit_link/789591\']);" href="'.$item->offerURL.'"><img src="'.$item->imageList->image[0]->sourceURL.'" width="100"></a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

print 'offerURL.'">imageList->image[0]->sourceURL.'" width="100">';

should be

print 'offerURL.'">imageList->image[0]->sourceURL.'" width="100">';

Assuming _trackPageView is a variable. Otherwise, escape the single quotes: \'

Answer (score 0):

I assume the line you're getting the error for is:

```
print '<a rel="nofollow" onclick="javascript:_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/outgoing/article_exit_link/789591']);" href="'.$item->offerURL.'"><img src="'.$item->imageList->image[0]->sourceURL.'" width="100"></a>';
```

You're using single quotes (`'`) to delimit your string, but the string also contains single quotes (for instance, `'_trackPageview'`. You need to escape these (`\'`), because otherwise PHP takes them to mean the end of your string, and gives you the unexpected token error you're experiencing.